# Adding parameterless constructor to non-serializable, extendable class

Tags: java, serialization

What is special about addid a parameterless constructor to a non serializable, extendable class.

In Effective java , the author talks about this topic.

> Naively adding a parameterless constructor and a
>   separate initialization method to a class whose remaining constructors establish its
>   invariants would complicate the state space, increasing the likelihood of error.

*The following code is copied from Effective Java 2nd Edition[Page 292-293]*

```
 public class AbstractFoo {
private int x, y; // Our state

// This enum and field are used to track initialization
private enum State {
    NEW, INITIALIZING, INITIALIZED
};

private final AtomicReference<State> init = new AtomicReference<State>(
        State.NEW);

public AbstractFoo(int x, int y) {
    initialize(x, y);
}

// This constructor and the following method allow
// subclass's readObject method to initialize our state.
protected AbstractFoo() {
}

protected final void initialize(int x, int y) {
    if (!init.compareAndSet(State.NEW, State.INITIALIZING))
        throw new IllegalStateException("Already initialized");
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    // ... // Do anything else the original constructor did
    init.set(State.INITIALIZED);
}

// These methods provide access to internal state so it can
// be manually serialized by subclass's writeObject method.
protected final int getX() {
    checkInit();
    return x;
}

protected final int getY() {
    checkInit();
    return y;
}

// Must call from all public and protected instance methods
private void checkInit() {
    if (init.get() != State.INITIALIZED)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Uninitialized");
}
// ... // Remainder omitted

    }
```

> All public and protected instance methods in AbstractFoo must invoke
>   checkInit before doing anything else. This ensures that method invocations fail
>   quickly and cleanly if a poorly written subclass fails to initialize an instance. Note
>   that the initialized field is an atomic reference (java.util.concurrent.
>   atomic.AtomicReference). This is necessary to ensure object integrity in
>   the face of a determined adversary. In the absence of this precaution, if one thread
>   were to invoke initialize on an instance while a second thread attempted to use
>   it, the second thread might see the instance in an inconsistent state.

Why are we doing this? I did not fully understand this. Can anyone explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate initialization method is very useful when you have multi-threading issue. You can see good article : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue when reading the book. I was bit confused in that exact place. With bit of research I found out this.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Read this. According to that 
"During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is serializable. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored from the stream"

I think this answers your question.
Hope this would be helpfull.
If there any thing wrong in this comment please feel free to correct it.